# Gaussian Elimination - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to solve a system of equations using Gaussian Elimiation but I'm really having some trouble as I seem to be getting too many 0's. Here are the equations:

+  +  =

+  −  =

+  +  = 4

To get my first 0 in the bottom left corner, I have performed R3 - R2 + R1:

```
[1 1 1 = 1

4 3 -1 = 6

0 3 5 = -1]
```

Then to get the "0" on the second row, I perform R2 * R1 - R2:

```
[1 1 1 = 1

0  0  0 = 0

0 3 5 = -1]
```

Already I can see this is wrong as I have way too many 0's and can't see how I'll be able to get my diagonal 1's. My issue with this method is that I'm aware of what I'm allowed to do, but I'm not aware of what I'm **not** allowed to do.

Could someone please step me through a better way of performing Gaussian Elimitation with these equations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the problema correctly? Aren't there too many $x$? From the first equation, you get $x=\frac{1}{3}$; from the second, $x=3$, and $x=\frac{11}{4}$ from the third. Maybe you meant to use different letters?

Comment: You mean $x+y+z = 1$ not $x+x+x=1$ right?

Comment: In any case, you cannot "multiply" two rows, and I put that in quote because there is not just one way to multiply to vectors.

Comment: For some reason the question has been typed out as all x's, strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the RREF matrix we are allowed to do three types of elementary row operations:

1) Swapping two rows

2) Multiplying a row by a non-zero number

3) Adding a multiple of one row to another row

For example we can obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\4&3&-1&6\\3&5&3&4 \end{bmatrix}
\stackrel{R3-3R1 + R2-4R1}
\to\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&-1&-5&2\\0&2&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
\stackrel{R3+2R2}
\to\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&-1&-5&2\\0&0&-10&5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help @gimusi. I'm able to convert the diagonal numbers to 1 by multiplying through the reciprocal of the leading coefficent for each row,  but I seem to be getting z = -5/8, do you know if this is correct?

Comment: Yes we see indeed from the third equation that $-8z=5\implies z=-5/8$

Comment: Okay so can I just continue to solve for both x and y?

Comment: yes exactly, once you have z proceed with the second equation that is $-y-4z=2$ to find y.

Comment: Okay so I have x = 3, y = -9/2 and z = -5/8, do you think this is correct?

Comment: Just double checked, I think I made a mistake!

Comment: From the second equation it should be y=8 if I’m not wrong.

Comment: I'm confused, with y = 8, the y equation doesn't work :( Would you mind updating your answer to show how to properly do this?

Comment: For z we are ok. For y from the second equation in the RREF we have $-y-4z=2\implies -y+10=2\implies y=8$ now we can find x from the first equation.

Comment: Ok so I'm working out x + 8(y) + -5/8 = 1. But if 8 + -5/8 = 59/8 which is 7.3 converted then x must equal like -6 or something? It's definitely a negative number i'm sure right?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the second row and then in the third, I fix. The third becomes-10z=5 z=-1/2, the second is -y-5z=2 that is -y=2-5/2=-1/2 then y=1/2. Therefore we have x+1/2-1/2=1 x=1.

Comment: Yes! These are the results I had I just wasn't sure if they were correct! Thank you!

Comment: @nonbee You are welcome, remember that you can accept an answer among the given if it solved the OP, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

> R2 * R1 - R2

This is not a valid elementary row operation. You can't multiply two rows together. You can only multiply them by (nonzero!) constants, or add and subtract them from each other, or swap them around.

Try something like $R_2 - 4R_1$ instead.